# Se muestra el objeto a pesar de haber sido eliminado del array en JavqaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy haciendo un juego que consiste en que aparecen una serie de pokemon. Al darle a un botón se detiene en uno al azar y se trata de escribir el pokemon que es. Si se acierta ese pokemon se elimina del array de objetos y no vuelve a aparecer. El problema está en que el pokemon sigue apareciendo a pesar de estar eliminado del array. Para guardar los pokemon estoy usando un array de objetos que guarda el id, el nombre y el sprite que se muestra por pantalla. Cuando se acierta el pokemon ese objeto se elimina del array usando el método `splice` Este es el código conflictivo.

```
    import * as pk from "./pokemon.js";
    
    const btnComprobar = document.querySelector(".comprobar");
    const correcto = document.querySelector(".aciertos");
    const incorrecto = document.querySelector(".errores");
    const contadorMinutos = document.querySelector(".minutos");
    const contadorSegundos = document.querySelector(".segundos");
    const btnDetener = document.querySelector("#detener");
    const formularioBucle = document.getElementsByClassName("formulario")[0];
    const formularioComprobar = document.getElementsByClassName("formulario")[1];
    const respuesta = document.getElementById("respuesta");
    
    let random = () => Math.round(Math.random() * (9 - 1) + 1);
    
    // La variable cronometro está en uso
    let nombre, sprite, id, cronometro, aciertos = 0, errores = 0, seg = 0, min = 0;
    
// El método llamada imprime por pantalla el sprite del pokemon aleatorio
    const llamada = () => {
        const post_it = document.querySelector(".post-it");
      let idRandom = random() - 1;
        
      nombre = pk.pokemon[idRandom].nombre;
      sprite = pk.pokemon[idRandom].img;
      id = pk.pokemon[idRandom].id;
        
        //console.log(pk.pokemon[idRandom]);
    // Aquí se muestra por pantalla el sprite del pokemon
      post_it.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${sprite}" alt"${nombre}"/>
        `;
    }; // Llamada
    
// Este botón comrpueba si él nombre del pokemon se ha acertado o no. Si acierta se elimina del array. Si falla aumenta el contador de errores en uno y no se elimina.
    btnComprobar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (respuesta.value.length === 0) {
            alert("El campo está vacío");
      } else {
            if (respuesta.value === nombre) {
                alert("Felicidades. Has acertado");
          aciertos++;
          actualizarPuntuacion();
    
                // BUG El pokemon se elimina de la lista pero se sigue mostrando
                pk.pokemon.splice(id - 1, 1);
    
        } else {
                errores++;
          actualizarPuntuacion();
          alert("Has fallado");
        }
            
        formularioBucle.classList.remove("ocultar");
        respuesta.value = "";
        formularioComprobar.classList.add("ocultar");
        iniciar();
      }
    }); // btnComprobar.addEventistener
```

Comment: pk.pokemon.splice(id - 1, 1);  Porque id-1???

Comment: Para borrar el índice adecuado. Coge el id del pokemon que el primero de todos es 1, le resto 1 y así tengo el índice del pokemon a borrar. Lo he probado y borra del array el pokemon adecuado